# Accessing remote browsers on client machines

Tags: python, selenium

I have a portal built with flask, through which the selenium gets initialized and opens up the given web application in chrome browser. Here the selenium is ran from the python code to get access to the browsers.

I'm facing problem in deployment of the application.
I have deployed the portal on a virtual box VM. Everthing works perfectly.
But when I try to access the portal from the other machine using Virtual machine ip address, portal is rendering but, the chrome browser is opening on virtual box VM istead of user's (client) machine. This is supposed to be accessable to clients but this is not happening as expected.

Can someone please help me in fixing this issue. Please find the code below.

```
def run_selenium(passed_url):
    browser = request.user_agent.browser
    version = request.user_agent.version and int(request.user_agent.version.split('.')[0])
    platform = request.user_agent.platform
    uas = request.user_agent.string

    if 'OPR' in uas:
        browser = 'Opera'
        driver = webdriver.Opera()
    elif browser == 'chrome':
        browser = 'Chrome'

    #location of chromedriver needed for running seenium on chrome browser. chromedriver is uploaded to github repo
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(conf.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH[0])
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        browser == 'Firefox'
        driver = webdriver.Firefox() 

    driver.get(passed_url) #passing url taken from form
    head_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_tag_name('head')) # waiting for page to atleast load <head> element fully so script could be injected
    if head_element:
        print ("injecting script")

        # rawgit.com MaxCDN service used.. js file is at github repo annoletjs/master
        driver.execute_script("!function(){function e(){script=document.createElement('script'),script.type='text/javascript',script.src='//rawgit.com/SSS-Studio-development/annoletjs/tagging/annolet_main.js',document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)}($=window.jQuery)?e():(script=document.createElement('script'),script.src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js',script.onload=e,document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script))}();")
        print ("injected")
    return 'annotate'
```

Comment: Do you want clients to be able to run tests and see the tests run on their machine? If so, you could install a VNC server on the VM and then show the client a VNC client session using, for example, [realvnc](https://developer.realvnc.com/docs/latest/api/python/index.html)

Comment: Or, if you control the client machines you could set up a [Selenium Grid](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-grid/8702/selenium-grid-configuration) and make each client machine a Node.